# C++ cost of declaring a reference?

Tags: c++, reference

Does declaring a reference result in runtime costs ?

```
Typename a;    
auto& b=a;
func(b);
```

Does declaring a reference inside of a loop result in multiple times of runtime costs ?

```
Typename a=Typename();//default constructor
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    auto& b=a;
    func(b);
}
```

Or

```
Typename a=Typename();//default constructor
auto& b=a;
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    func(b);
}
```

better?

Comment: Generate the assembly code.  Secondly, compiler optimization techniques are excellent these days.  A compiler will know how to optimize that loop (at least it should be able to).

Answer (score 1):

Underneath the hood, references are generally implemented using a pointer - so there may be the additional cost imposed by this (the memory cost of the pointer, as well as the runtime cost of the de-reference operation). However, if the reference is used only as a local alias (as you are doing here), compilers are capable of completely optimising this out.

This behaviour though can depend on your compiler and optimisation settings. For your specific example: Using GCC 5.2, with optimisation disabled the reference inside the loop generates an additional de-reference operation. However, as soon as you turn on optimisation they both generate identical output.

Comment: _"Underneath the hood, references are implemented using a pointer"_ - Not always. Local references are typically treated strictly as aliases and should have zero cost.